# Is getExternalFilesDir() private?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to store music files users can download with my application, but I don't want them to be publicly visible to 99% of users (I'm excluding rooted devices or special cases)

I'm not worried about the people that go above and beyond to get the audio out by using special tools or a rooted phone.

I am trying to understand the docs but it's not 100% clear to me that `getExternalFilesDir()` is good to use for that purpose.

Also, the library I'm currently using uses the following line:

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath()
```

Is this 100% interchangeable if I just replace it with...

```
Environment.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).getAbsolutePath()
```

(notice I changed both the directory function, as well as the `DIRECTORY` type (from `PICTURES` to `MUSIC`)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is getExternalFilesDir() private?

No. Any user and any app (with `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` or `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`) can access [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

> Is this 100% interchangeable if I just replace it with..

That won't compile due to imbalanced parentheses. Also, the values are different (`PICTURES` versus `MUSIC`). Ignoring that, it is "interchangeable" insofar as they will both work and will both be on external storage. However, they are not the same thing. The first one is the user's standard `PICTURES` directory; the second one is a directory dedicated for pictures that is unique to your app. Also, the former requires `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` on all devices; the latter requires it only for Android 4.3 and below.

> I don't want them to be publicly visible to 99% of users (I'm excluding rooted devices or special cases)

Use [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) (e.g., `getFilesDir()`).

Comment: Thanks for your very very helpful answer, that helps a lot. i will make your reply as the answer, but can you help me clarify one final thing? So aside from the parentheses I broke, how would you write this one line from the library I'm using, if I were to use `getFilesDir()` like you say? https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs/blob/9a4c2d890fedeca1bf5a8b56d181eecf15900934/android/src/main/java/com/rnfs/RNFSManager.java#L300

Comment: @Tallboy: I can't really answer that, insofar as I know nothing about this plugin. Replacing the `Environment` bit with the same `this.getReactApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()` from the previous statement might be a starting point. But I'd focus on talking to the developers of the plugin and asking their advice.

Comment: Thanks! That helps

Answer (score 1):

Use `getFilesDir()` instead. Thats private app memory.

Answer (score 0):

if you put "." before folder name this folder be hidden
e.g:

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File myDir = new File(root + "/.myFolderName");
```

Comment: This is the library I'm using. If I put what you have in here do you think that will work? I'm not an Android developer if you cant tell haha: https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs/blob/9a4c2d890fedeca1bf5a8b56d181eecf15900934/android/src/main/java/com/rnfs/RNFSManager.java

Comment: Note that "hidden" is not the same as "inaccessible".  Particularly if they are working from a Windows computer, it will not even be hidden

Comment: Is there any way to make it hidden outside of all the public folders, and only available on rooted devices?